# iPhone Shortcut to change app location services preferences

Tags: iphone, ios, automation, shortcuts-app, gps

My motorcycle GPS is connected to an App that must allow location services to “Always” to work correctly (“While using the app” does not work).

As I’d like to turn the location services off when I’m not riding, The path would be the following: Settings->Motorcycle App->Location->Always (or “Never” when I stop using my bike).

Is there any way I can quickly access the setting with a shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do this for the State Farm Drive Safe & Save app - for me the URL was

```
prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION/com.statefarm.DriveSafeAndSave
```

Open Shortcuts App / + / Add Action / Web / **URL** / input `prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION/com.statefarm.DriveSafeAndSave` / Add Action / **Open URLs**

For other apps, the URL follows the format:

```
prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION/bundle.id.here
```

Please, note, it is better to add two actions - one with the URL value and the other to open it, as seen on the screenshot:

[image: "URL" and "Open URLs" actions]

as with the single one filled with the URL value directly, the shortcut redirected me to Safari, looking for the bundle id on the web.

And you can find the bundle ID of your specific app like this:

1. Google the App name with a Desktop browser and open the apps.apple.com store link - in my case this was

```
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/drive-safe-save/id1043246998
```

2. Extract the number after 'id' in the URL - 1043246998 in this case
3. Create a new link a new link by adding your id number and country to this:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=??&country=??
```

example:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1043246998&country=us
```

4. open a new browser tab and go to your created link - this will prompt you to download a text file (probably named 1.txt) - do so and open it in a text editor such as Notepad or TextEdit
5. Search for the bundleId entry - here's an example for the bundle ID for the Yahoo News App, which is com.yahoo.frontpage
   [image: Example bundleID for Yahoo News App]

Instructions for finding the bundle ID are from this site, which also describes another method if you happen to have the app's .ipa file.

[How to Find Bundle ID of an iOS app ? Step by Step](https://mrvirk.com/how-to-find-app-bundle-id-ios.html)

Here's where I found the URL - It has useful URLs for other settings, too: [An updated list of Settings URLs](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/i9rjbh/an_updated_list_of_settings_urls/)

Comment: You should [edit] and include the steps to finding the Bundle ID in your answer, otherwise this is a bit of a link only answer, w.r.t. that part.

Comment: @Greenonline better? I couldn't figure out how to indent within the numbered list, but at least I know how to make those greyed out squares for the URL's now